# Override function in base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

In the below example, I want to replace part of a calculation without having to re-implement the entire calculation in the derived sub classes.

```
class DummyCalcBase
{
    public int changeable_part()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public int common_calculation()
    {
        return 5 * changeable_part();
    }
}

class DummyCalc : DummyCalcBase
{
    public new int changeable_part()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c = new DummyCalcBase().common_calculation();
        Console.WriteLine("Base gives " + c.ToString());

        int c2 = new DummyCalc().common_calculation();
        Console.WriteLine("Calc gives " + c2.ToString());
    }
}
```

This then gives output:
Base gives 25
Calc gives 25

What I would like is to get DummyCalc().common_calculation() to call the new changeable_part (and give the answer 50).

This would mean I don't have to copy and paste the same method into sub classes.

Comment: `changeable_part` in `DummyCalcBase` should be `virtual`, and be `override`n in `DummyCalc`.

Comment: As an aside, even more striking is it to have a base reference to a derived and exploit polymorphism (after honing the virtual/override advice of the others): `DummyCalcBase dcb = new DummyCalc(); Console.WriteLine(dcb.common_calculation());` should print 50, even though dcb is a of type "reference of DummyCalcBase".

Comment: You've shadowed the method not overridden it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can `override` method if it is `virtual`

```
class DummyCalcBase
{
    public virtual int changeable_part()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public int common_calculation()
    {
        return 5 * changeable_part();
    }
}

class DummyCalc : DummyCalcBase
{
    public override int changeable_part()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

methods with `new` keyword only hide methods of base class

if method is virtual, the following code will compute 50:

```
DummyCalcBase dummy = new DummyCalc();
int calc = dummy.common_calculation();
```

[SO: new vs override difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/c-new-versus-override)

Answer (score 4):

Mark the method in the base class as either [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you want to provide a default implementation that derived types can override, or [`abstract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you want to leave the implementation up to derived types.

Then simply `override` those methods in your derived types, and provide functionality as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario is as simple as you describe here, go for the virtual method, with an override method in the sub-class. If your calculation is more complex, you should take a look at the strategy pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Your code will than look something like this:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    int getValue();
}

public class Context
{
    private readonly IStrategy strategy;

    public Context(IStrategy strategy)
    {
       this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public int common_calculation()
    {
        return 5 * strategy.getValue();
    }
}

public class FiveStrategy : IStrategy
{
     public int getValue()
     {
         return 5;
     }
}

public class TenStrategy : IStrategy
{
    public int getValue()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context5 = new Context(new FiveStrategy());
        Console.WriteLine(context5.common_calculation());

        var context10 = new Context(new TenStrategy());
        Console.WriteLine(context10.common_calculation());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```