# Why does the C# dictionary not call the hidden GetHashCode method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've a project where I am extensively using the generic C# [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). I require composite keys, so I've been using [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) as keys. At some point I was wondering whether it would be beneficial to use a custom class which caches the hash code:

```
public class CompositeKey<T1, T2> : Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly int _hashCode;

    public CompositeKey(T1 t1, T2 t2) : base(t1, t2)
    {
        _hashCode = base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public new int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _hashCode;
    }
}
```

I used `new` instead of `override` because I thought it would not make a difference for this test, since I was defining the dictionary using the concrete type:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<CompositeKey<string, int>, int>();
```

I noticed, however, that my custom `GetHashCode` method is not called at all. When I changed `new` to `override` it got called as expected.

Can somebody explain why the hidden `GetHashCode` method is not called? I would expect this behavior if I would define the dictionary like this

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, int>();
```

but not if I specify the `CompositeKey` type explicitly as in my example.

P.S. I know that hiding the `GetHashCode` method is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Hiding is a bad idea, because it causes this issue!

Comment: Here's a post explaining the difference between new and override ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override

Comment: As an aside if you think your hashcode algorithm needs to be cached it's probably either a bad algorithm or you're caching unnecessarily.

Comment: True, it is definitely a micro optimization, but I was still curious whether it would make a measurable difference. In my test case the `CompositeKey` even performed slightly worse than the `Tuple` (when using `override` and the cached hash code).

Comment: @AndyJ I know that hiding usually is a bad idea and I would never use it in such a scenario. But assuming someone would have shown me my example and asked me whether it would make a difference in this specific case to use `new` instead of `override` I would have said no. But I guess you'll learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can somebody explain why the hidden GetHashCode method is not called?
>   I would expect this behavior if I would define the dictionary like
>   this

To be able to call `CompositeKey.GetHashCode` method, one must have the reference of the instance of `CompositeKey` typed as `CompositeKey` in compile time.

But codebase of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` isn't aware of your `CompositeKey` class(obviously). All it knows is `TKey`(generic type parameter) which is as equivalent as having `System.Object` without any constraints. Because you can't call any methods of `T` other than which is declared in `System.Object` without a constraint.

So, Dictionary ends up calling `Object.GetHashCode` which isn't overridden in your class --and thus it is not called.

Answer (score 4):

The overload resolution for method calls in generic types happens when the unbound generic type (e.g. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) is compiled, not when a closed type (e.g. `Dictionary<CompositeKey<string, int>, int>`) is constructed.

Since there is no constraint on `TKey` in `Dictionary<,>`, the only overload of `GetHashCode()` available is `object.GetHashCode()`. Constructing a type where there is a better overload of `GetHashCode()` doesn't change the initial overload resolution.

It is not only restricted to methods hidden with `new`. The same happens with overloaded methods:

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public bool Equal(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1.Equals(t2);
    }
}

class X : IEquatable<X>
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("object.Equals");
        return true;
    }

    public bool Equals(X other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IEquatable.Equals");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `X.Equals(X)` overload will never be used

```
var test = new Generic<X>();
test.Equal(new X(), new X()); 

// prints "object.Equals"
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I did not know that the constraints had any other effect except from a type check when you're trying to construct a new instance of a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the previous answers. The problem with new is that it ONLY overrides the method IF the consumer is directly operating on the class (in this case your CompositeKey class.) Any call on any base class that your CompositeKey derives from will NOT call your new member.

So if in the following:

- CompositeKey.GetHashCode() <--- Will call your new method.
- Tuple.GetHashCode() <--- Will **not** call your new method.
- Object.GetHashCode() <--- Will **not** call your new method.

As previous answers have highlighted, because EqualityComparer (the class Dictionary uses) specifies that T is a non-constrained generic, then the compiler will only support the **lowest common denominator for all T** that could be passed to it, which is the methods directly on Object.

Therefore the call is effectively: ((Object)key).GetHashCode(). From above you can see that this will not call your new method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the type constraints on generics. Here is a simplified program to show the problem.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        TestMethod(bar);
        TestMethod2(bar);
    }

    public static void TestMethod<T>(T obj) where T : Foo
    {
        obj.Test();
        obj.Test2();
    }

    public static void TestMethod2<T>(T obj) where T : Bar
    {
        obj.Test();
        obj.Test2();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    public virtual void Test2()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public new void Test()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    public override void Test2()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

In `TestMethod()` you hit the breakpoint in `Foo.Test()` and `Bar.Test2()` but in `TestMethod2()` you hit the breakpoint in `Bar.Test()` and `Bar.Test2()`, this is because in the first method you are constrained to type `Foo` or lower so when the compiler compiles it binds to the call on `Foo`, it is the same as if the function was written as

```
public static void TestMethod<T>(T obj)
{
    ((Foo)obj).Test(); //You would expect this to call Foo.Test() b\c of shadowing
    ((Foo)obj).Test2(); //You would expect this to call Bar.Test2() b\c of overloading
}
```

Now, on to your problem, the comparer that is being used is [written as](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,ac282b3e1817bb9b)

```
[Serializable]
internal class ObjectEqualityComparer<T>: EqualityComparer<T>
{
    [Pure]
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        if (x != null) {
            if (y != null) return x.Equals(y);
            return false;
        }
        if (y != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    [Pure]
    public override int GetHashCode(T obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
    //...
}
```

There is no constraint on `T` so those two methods are behaving as if they are written as

```
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        if (x != null) {
            if (y != null) return ((object)x).Equals(y);
            return false;
        }
        if (y != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    [Pure]
    public override int GetHashCode(T obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return ((object)obj).GetHashCode();
    }
```

That is why your function is only called when you overrode it and not when you shadowed it.