# Update an inherited method C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Pretty new guy here, starting to look deeper onto C#.

I was wondering if you can "update" an inherited method. Here in my example the "Mage" class inherits from "Hero". Both have a "Shout" method, yet the Mage shout should add a line of text to the screen, but I only get the Hero's one.

I don't want to override Hero's Shout, but "update it" so Hero's childrens can shout something else. I was expecting new to let me modify the old methods while still using it, but no luck. What am I missing?

```
public class Hero
{
    protected string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Hero(string n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }

    public virtual void Shout()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am {0} and I am a hero! ", Name);
    }
}

public class Mage : Hero
{
    public Mage(string n) : base(n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }

    public new void Shout()
    {
        base.Shout();
        // Next line does not print...
        Console.WriteLine("Also, I am a fierce Mage!");
    }
}
```

Tanks for any help, tip,...!

Main could be:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var h = new Hero("Paul One-Eye");
        // Old line, not working
        // var m = new Hero("Zangdar the Just");
        var m = new Mage("Zangdar the Just");

        h.Shout();
        m.Shout();
    }
}
```

Expected output should be :

> I am Paul One-Eye and I am a hero!
>
> I am Zangdar the Just and I am a hero!
>
> Also, I am a fierce Mage!

EDIT:
Overriding the method like this DOES change SOMETHING:

```
    public override void Shout()
    {
        base.Shout();
        Console.WriteLine("I am a fierce Mage!");
    }
```

Comment: "so Hero's childrens can shout something else"  That´s exactly what overriding a method will do. Why don´t you want to override it?

Comment: Overriding **IS** updating it. You can't both do it and not do it. Also you're not making a mage the second time.

Comment: You should have a closer look on what the `new` and `override`-keywords do on a member, for instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override

Comment: You are not creating a Mage...

Comment: Both `h` and `m` are of type `Hero`. How should the compiler know it should infer the `Mage`s method when you don´t day him that any of the instances *is* a `Mage`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Indeed, stupidest mistake ever, tanks...

Comment: Voted to close this question as OP made a simple typo by not using derived type and this problem can no longer be reproduced

Comment: "Overriding the method like this DOES change SOMETHING" I suppose it changed exactly what you intended it to, so we can close this question as typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is working fine But you initialized your Mage with the Base Hero class

**You did**

```
var h = new Hero("Paul One-Eye");
var m = new Hero("Zangdar the Just");
```

**It should be**

```
var h = new Hero("Paul One-Eye");
var m = new Mage("Zangdar the Just");
```

Comment: Indeed, tanks... I'm a bit ashamed of this one.

Comment: Good point!! Not using an inherited type means this, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering why won't you override the base class method and extend it?

```
public class Mage : Hero
{
    public Mage(string n) : base(n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }

    public override void Shout()
    {
        base.Shout();
        Console.WriteLine("Also, I am a fierce Mage!");
    }
}
```

"new" modifier is used to hide the base class method while "override" modifier is used to extend the base class method (and this is exactly what you want), more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example

Your main is this:

```
 class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var h = new Hero("Paul One-Eye");
        var m = new Mage("Zangdar the Just");
        Hero m2 = (Hero)new Mage("Copyright the Infringed");

        h.Shout();
        m.Shout(); 
        m2.Shout();
    }
}


public class Mage : Hero {
    public new void Shout() {
        base.Shout();  Console.WriteLine("Also, I am a fierce Mage!");
    }
}
```

Prints:

> I am Paul One-Eye and I am a hero!
>
> I am Zangdar the Just and I am a hero! Also, I am a fierce Mage!
>
> I am Copyright the Infringed and I am a hero!

However if you do this:

```
public class Mage : Hero {
    public override void Shout() {
        base.Shout();  Console.WriteLine("Also, I am a fierce Mage!");
    }
}
```

Prints:

> I am Paul One-Eye and I am a hero!
>
> I am Zangdar the Just and I am a hero! Also, I am a fierce Mage!
>
> I am Copyright the Infringed and I am a hero! Also, I am a fierce Mage!

Take your pick. If you want the hero shout to always be a hero shout even when the hero can potentially be a mage, use new. If you want the hero shout to always reflect what subtype the hero is use `override`

Comment: Tanks for the explanation! :)