# Overridden Web API Method Returns "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a generic Web API controller that does CRUD which is like this:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController {
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual IHttpActionResult Post(T entity)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public virtual IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
}
```

ObjectController is derived from BaseController but it overrides the Put Method

```
public class ObjectController : BaseController {
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/Object")]
    public override IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have no problem calling all methods in a controller when none is overridden. For example,

```
public class Object2Controller : BaseController { }
```

Invoking the POST method returns 405 method not allowed.
What is wrong with my code?

**EDIT** This is not a duplicate question because I can call PUT in other controllers.

**EDIT 2** Changed new to override(virtual) but still getting the same error

**EDIT 3** Provided a working controller

Comment: That isn't overriden, you've simply hidden the original method. BaseController should declare `public virtual IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)` and ObjectController should declare `public override IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override) for new vs override.

Comment: what is the Uri of your request

Comment: @rajeemcariazo if you *can* use PUT in other controllers there's no reason to chase WebDAV. You have to make the base `PUT` virtual though otherwise and use the `override` keyword because right now you aren't overriding anything.

Comment: @rajeemcariazo you can't just say "I can use PUT in other controllers" though. You have to provide a *reproducible* example, *and* provide your `web.config` so people don't have to guess about WebDAV. What URL causes the problem? Does it differ in any way compared to other PUTs ? If you don't provide the actual configuration, URLs, code, people would have to guess just to try to reproduce the problem

Comment: @rajeemcariazo without that information, I'm afraid this question will have to be closed. Besides, I suspect that simply trying to create a new, simple Web API project that exhibits the same problem will either not reproduce it or show you what's wrong. A missed web.config setting? Or a WebDAV setting on *one* Application pool/Virtual Directory? Do you use *Areas* perhaps with their own web.config? Tried to host under a SharePoint root?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use VIRTUAL keyword in your base class? ..
VIRTUAL is made specifically to let developer ovverride methods in derived classes

something like:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController {
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual  IHttpActionResult Post(T entity)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public virtual IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
}
```

and then:

```
public  class ObjectController : BaseController {
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/Object")]
    public override IHttpActionResult Put(T entity)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I'm still getting 405 method not allowed

Comment: @rajeemcariazo post a *reproducible* example. Apart from the obvious mistakes in your code people can't guess what the rest of the project looks like

Comment: can you also post your FRONT END code? .. cause error looks like you're using the WRONG verbs