# Why does Python.NET use the base method instead of the method from a derived class?

Tags: c#, python, .net, oop, python.net

**Edit: This will be fixed in a new version of pythonnet (when [this](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/756) pull request is merged).**

I have a problem with Python.NET inheritance. I have a DLL which consists of the following code:

```
using System;

namespace InheritanceTest
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public bool Transmit()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class InheritedClass: BaseClass
    {
        public new bool Transmit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect a call to the `Transmit` method of an instance of `InheritedClass` to write to the console and return true and the `Transmit` method of `BaseClass` to throw a NotImplementedException.

When running the following python code:

```
## setup
import clr
import os

clr.AddReference(os.getcwd() + '\\InheritanceTest.dll')
import InheritanceTest

## method test

base_class = InheritanceTest.BaseClass()
base_class.Transmit() # throws a NotImplementedException as expected

inherited_class = InheritanceTest.InheritedClass()
inherited_class.Transmit() # still throws a NotImplementedException, although it should call InheritedClass.Transmit
```

I am using pythonnet version 2.3.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1. Thanks for your help!

Edit: This is not answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override). There, it is said that

> The new modifier instructs the compiler to use your child class implementation instead of the parent class implementation. Any code that is not referencing your class but the parent class will use the parent class implementation.

which is clearly not what happens here.

Edit 2: This seems to be a problem with the pythonnet library. [The issue is now on github.](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/755)

Comment: You are using http://pythonnet.github.io/ ?

Comment: Yes. [This](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) PyPi package.

Comment: @BenjaminMinixhofer this is a valid bug report even in the master branch, please file it on github and contributions are welcome!

Comment: get my 200 points if you fix this issue in pythonnet!

Comment: @BenjaminMinixhofer But does the same issue happen when you use the virtual-override approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pythonnet` method resolution (the `Bind` method found in the `methodbinder.cs` file) could be improved quite a lot IMHO. Anyway, this method currently doesn't really care about  types hierarchies.

One simple solution is to change the `MethodSorter` class so it favors derived class when it sorts methods to determine which one will be choosen by the `Bind` call.

Before:

```
internal class MethodSorter : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(object m1, object m2)
    {
        int p1 = MethodBinder.GetPrecedence((MethodBase)m1);
        int p2 = MethodBinder.GetPrecedence((MethodBase)m2);
        if (p1 < p2)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (p1 > p2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After:

```
internal class MethodSorter : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(object m1, object m2)
    {
        var me1 = (MethodBase)m1;
        var me2 = (MethodBase)m2;
        if (me1.DeclaringType != me2.DeclaringType)
        {
            // m2's type derives from m1's type, favor m2
            if (me1.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(me2.DeclaringType))
                return 1;

            // m1's type derives from m2's type, favor m1
            if (me2.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(me1.DeclaringType))
                return -1;
        }

        int p1 = MethodBinder.GetPrecedence((MethodBase)m1);
        int p2 = MethodBinder.GetPrecedence((MethodBase)m2);
        if (p1 < p2)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (p1 > p2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note I've not ran extensive tests, so I'm not sure this will not break something else. As I say this whole method binding code seems fragile.

Comment: would you mind submitting a PR with this proposed fix to pythonnet? if this passes the existing tests in CI, then this should make it into pythonnet.

Comment: @denfromufa - I've done it but github seems to currently have weird performance/cache/whatever issues...