# How to rename an inherited API member in a subclass?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Say I have:

```
public class Parent{
    [ApiMember(Name = "parentItem")]
    public string Item {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Child : Parent {
    [ApiMember(Name = "childItem")]
    public new string Item {get; set;}
}
```

Since the 'Item' property in the parent class should be hidden, why does making a request with `{"childItem": "something"}` returns `Could not find property childItem on RequestObject`? That said, what is the best way (or is there a way) to rename inherited API members/properties in the subclass?

Comment: [Related reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes affect serialization where as `[Api*]` attributes are only used to document and add extra metadata about your API, but it doesn't affect serialization behavior.

So you should instead change your DTOs to:

```
[DataContract]
public class Parent
{
    [DataMember(Name = "parentItem")]
    public virtual string Item { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Child : Parent 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "childItem")]
    public override string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Where they will be used when serializing in most of ServiceStack's serializers, e.g:

```
var json1 = new Parent { Item = "parent" }.ToJson();
json1.Print();

var json2 = new Child { Item = "child" }.ToJson();
json2.Print();
```

Which outputs:

```
{"parentItem":"parent"}
{"childItem":"child"}
```

You can [try this example Live on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=a9ded232cbe3f1a6c185219efe30e669).

Answer (score 1):

Try making the property virtual in the parent and then simply override it (without `new` keyword) in the child class like that:

```
public class Parent{
    [ApiMember(Name = "parentItem")]
    public virtual string Item {get; set;}
}

public class Child : Parent {
    [ApiMember(Name = "childItem")]
    public override string Item {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I tried to do `public override string Item {get; set;} = "test default"` and I can see that the property is properly overriden as when I debug it, I can see the default value "test default". However, making a request with `{"childItem": "something"}`  still returns `Could not find property childItem on RequestObject`.

Comment: Please post more code, e.g. a controller that's supposed to handle the request.