# C# Problem with Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown binding

Tags: c#, binding, numericupdown

I have a `NumericUpDown` control, which is a part of a UserControl.
The UserControl has Value property:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public override double Value
{
    get { return this.ControlValue; }
    set
    {
        this.ControlValue = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
    }
}
```

I used `DataBindings` for the `NumericUpDown`:

```
NumericUpDown.DataBindings.Add(nameof(NumericUpDown.Value), this, nameof(UserControl.Value), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The Value property used to be Int32, but I had to change it to Double. And suddenly the binding stopped working.

I know for sure the Value property is changing, but the NumericUpDown's value doesn't.

**Correction: it appears the Binding only fails to update NumericUpDown's value when the Value property is changed. Changing NumericUpDown's value DOES change the Value property.**

Comment: any binding erros in your output?

Comment: No binding errors in the Output Window.

Comment: Probably you need to set the `Increment` property of the NUD to fit the double. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Tried to mess with the `Increment` property, no results.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem actually was not in the Binding or the NumericUpDown control, but rather in the "override" keyword. In this case, the binding was confused which property was changing - UserControl's Value or its base class. **This was solved by using "new" instead of "override".**

Still can't understand why I didn't have this problem earlier. This code is 4-5 months old and worked perfectly before I changed Value property type from Int32 to Double.

Comment: Maybe answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override can shed some light onto the result.