# Abstract class cast issue

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have this code:

```cs
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public new string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var dog = new Dog
    {
        Name = "Spark"
    };

    Console.WriteLine(dog.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(((Animal)dog).Name == null);
}
```

Which will output:

```
Spark
True
```

Why is the `Name` property `null` when casting it to `Animal`?

How to fix it, if I want to cast my object to `Animal`? How can I keep the properties values?

Comment: Delete `Name` in `Dog`. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper Updated my example, added ``JsonPropertyAttribute``, I want it to differ depending on the animal (Dog, Cat) so it isn't always ``name``

Comment: Well you never set the base name at all, you are just hiding the base property with the new keyword

Comment: Right, then change `new` to `override`, and make `Animal.Name` virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you expect is implemented by `override`, so you have to override property:

```
public override string Name { get; set; }
```

But in order to do that, you need mark that property as `abstract`, otherwise you will get an error:

> error CS0506: 'Dog.Name': cannot override inherited member 'Animal.Name' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override

[Refer to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override) There you can read:

> The override modifier may be used on virtual methods and must be used on abstract methods. This indicates for the compiler to use the last defined implementation of a method. Even if the method is called on a reference to the base class it will use the implementation overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
     string name = null;
     public new string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; base.Name = name; } } }
}
```