# OOPs clarification

Tags: c#, .net, oop

how to prevent a base class methode from being override by sub class

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to do anything special: methods are non-overridable by default. Rather, if you want the method to be overridable, you have to add the `virtual` keyword to its declaration.

Note however that even if a method is non-overridable, a derived class can *hide* it. More information here: [C# keyword usage virtual+override vs. new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new)

Comment: Yep! but c# compiler allow me to override the methods presents in bases class as default. that is why i confused.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, type "override" inside the class declaration and intellisense will show you a list of overridable methods. If you try to declare again any method not in this list, you are hiding it, not overriding it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a virtual method in a base class (ClassA), which is overriden in an inherited class (ClassB), and you want to prevent that a class that inherits from ClassB overrides this method, then, you have to mark this method as 'sealed' in ClassB.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual  void Somemethod() {}
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public sealed override void Somemethod() {}
}

public class ClassC : ClassB
{
     // cannot override Somemethod here.
}
```

Comment: That's a good point and probably the source of the problem for Sarathi1904.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use ABSTRACT for Parent Class . As a result you cant override by sub class

```
abstract main{
}

class sub extent main{
}
```