# The controller's action is ambiguous between the action of the baseclass with same name.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The current request for action 'Index' on controller type `ContactController` is ambiguous between the following action methods:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type RX.Web.Controllers.ContactController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type RX.Web.Controllers.CustomControllerBase2[[RX.Core.Model.Contact, RXTechJob.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

The Contact Controller:

```
        public virtual new ActionResult Index()
    {
        return base.Index();
    }
```

The base Controller:

```
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("Index", SelectAll());

    }
```

Why this happen? How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a second method called index that MVC does not know how to handle. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new) for a discussion on `virtual new` creating an additional not overriding method.

Instead for your contact controller consider something along the line of:

```
public override ActionResult Index() {
        return base.Index();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

Because stackoverflow did not recognise my Gooogle OpenID,so i create a new account and come back again :)

I can not use "override" because i am using [T4MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC&referringTitle=MVC) .

So i fix it like this:

base controller(replace "public" with "protected"):

```
        protected virtual ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("Index", SelectAll());

    }
```

contact controller:

```
        public virtual new ActionResult Index()
    {
        return base.Index();
    }
```

In the T4MVC auto generated code it can be overrided:

```
        public override System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() {
        var callInfo = new T4MVC_ActionResult(Area, Name, Actions.Index);
        return callInfo;
    }
```

Seemingly, everything  works fine now. :)