# Whats the effect of new keyword in return type of a C# method?

Tags: c#, syntax

Accidently I actually wrote this method:

```
public static new iTextSharp.text.Color ITextFocusColor()
{
   return new iTextSharp.text.Color(234, 184, 24);
}
```

It is working as suspected, but I was very surprised that is it allowed to use the new keyword in the return type of the method. Is there any effect/difference if i put there new or not? Or what is the new used for?

And is this also possible in other OO-languages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't affect the return type, it indicates that this method *hides* the method from the base class (rather than override it). It can be useful if you need to change the return type declared in the base class, for instance, but the hiding method won't participate in polymorphism, i.e. if you call `ITextFocusColor` on an instance of the derived class through a variable of the base class, the base implementation will be called (not the one declared with `new`)

See [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) for more details.

Comment: So static methods cannot override, but they can shadow.  Interesting.

Comment: I didn't notice the method was static when I answered... it makes the part about polymorphism largely irrelevant for this case ;)

Answer (score 5):

The `new` keyword specifies that you are deliberately providing a new implementation of a method or property that is already provided by a base class. It's there to make hiding of base class members a deliberate, self-documenting act.

If your base class doesn't have that method, it doesn't actually matter.

For more details, see the [C# specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E) (specifically, section 3.7.1.2 Hiding through inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

It is the [`new` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx). It hides members from a base class instead of overriding.

Comment: Not instead of overriding. Override is also explicit. It hides the member deliberately, avoiding a compiler error that would otherwise be raised.

Answer (score 1):

`new` keyword in method return type here hides the parent method.

Comment: The keyword is not part of the method return type. It does not affect what is returned by the method.