# What is the point of Virtual and Override? Doesn't C# Do the same thing without them?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

From my understanding, the `virtual` keyword allows you to use the base class' method, and `override` allows you to override it in a class that inherits from the base class. My confusion is that I just tested not using the virtual keyword in the base class' method definition and not including that method in the derived class, and I was still able to call the base class' method (it showed up in intellisense and ran). Also, I know that if i wanted a new method definition for that same method for my derived class that I could use the new keyword..

I am probably missing a key point but this is the way I understand it which is why I am confused as to the purpose of virtual and override

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# keyword usage virtual+override vs. new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My confusion is that I just tested not using the virtual keyword in
>   the base class' method definition and not including that method in the
>   derived class, and I was still able to call the base class' method (it
>   showed up in intellisense and ran).

This is expected behaviour.

[Virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) allows you to [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) a method which is defined in the base class, in other words extend the implementation of the  method in the derived class.

Differences between the new keyword and the override one [can be found on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx).

It is [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (private, public, protected) that affects if you are able to call the base class method in the derived class or not.

Comment: Isn't that what the "new" keyword does though? I just tested it and it ran the method from my derived class when I use the "new" keyword (isn't that the same as overriding?)

Comment: Added a link to a MSDN article that explains the difference between override and new.

Comment: Thanks Robin that MSDN article explained everything, very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The power of those keywords comes into play when you use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

I think an example helps understanding the most. Consider the following:

```
class Base {
  public virtual void f() { Console.WriteLine("Virtual Base"); }
}

class Override : Base {
  public override void f() { Console.WriteLine("Overridden derived"); }
}

class New : Base {
  public new void f() { Console.WriteLine("New derived"); }
}
```

Now, when you have an object of actual type `Derived` but static type `Base`, calling `f()` still will output "Overridden Derived":

```
Base obj = new Override();
obj.f(); // Overridden derived
```

With the `new` keyword you tell the runtime to stop looking for a method with that name starting from that class:

```
Base obj = new New();
obj.f(); // Virtual Base
```

In contrast to calling `f()` on a of type at least `New`:

```
New obj = new New();
obj.f(); // New derived
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtual allows you to override the base class method. You can still call the method without it but will not be able to override the method without it.

Sorry, I forgot to mention polymorphism. So if you have a base class that defines a method you can do something like this.

The below snippet will print from B

```
public class A
{
  virtual void foo
  {
    Console.WriteLine("From A");
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  override void foo()
  {
   Console.WriteLine("From B");
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
   A testA = new B();

   a.foo();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what the "new" keyword does? I just tested it and it ran the method from my derived class when I use the "new" keyword

Comment: @Maximus9000: the important concept here is [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 0):

To override a method in a base class the method you are overriding must be marked as virtual - you override a method using the override key word.

new in the context of a method is slightly different. It allows you to add a method in a subclass with the same name as a method in the base class. Which method gets called will depend on the reference that you use to access the method.

You can access any methods implemented in the base class (subject to access modifiers) regardless of whether they are marked virtual or not.

Comment: So in essence, you can use the 'new' keyword to effectively override a base class' method, it is just more proper to do it with virtual and override?

Comment: When using new you are not overriding, you are just adding another method which happens to have the same name as a method in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

When you mark a method as virtual or abstract, run-time type checking is used to determine the actual implementation of the method to call: it checks for the "most derived type" that implements/overrides the virtual method, and invokes that implementation. A plain method does not require run-time type checking.

Thus, the distinction between virtual and non-virtual has a meaningful impact on the semantics of your code, especially for public APIs. If you see this:

```
class A { void foo(); virtual void bar(); }
...
A myObject = getSomeObject();
myObject.foo();
myObject.bar();
```

You can be sure that the implementation of `foo` that is invoked is the one declared in class `A`. This is because only compile-time type checking is used to determine the method to be called. However, the specific implementation of `bar` that is invoked may be the implementation in some subclass of `A`, depending on the run-time type of `myObject`.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx