# Difference between "protected" and "virtual/override"

Tags: c#, oop

I couldn't understand the need or purpose of "protected" when i have "virtual/override" could someone explain me what do i need those 2 things if they are almost the same.

Edit:

Thanks for all the helpers, i now understand that "protected" is only for visibility purposes, while virtual/override is for class behavior.

Comment: This was answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new

Comment: These concepts are somewhat unrelated. One specifies visibility, the other specifies polymorphic behaviour. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @AntLaC you're mistaken that's New vs override which is different

Comment: @Antlac That's not the same thing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are certainly *not* almost the same.

The [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) modifier sets the *visibility*  of a field or method: such a member can only be accessed from the class it is defined in or from a derived class.

The [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) modifier specifies that the method it is applied to [can be `overridden`](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html) in a derived class.

These modifiers can be combined:  a method can be protected and virtual.

Comment: this answer only describes how it affects/limits syntax, not the functional implications, or when/why each should be used.

Comment: yes you are right... I was making a confusion with Java. I have been switching a lot back and forth lately. You have my humble apologies sir. You will have to edit the answer somehow... SO doesn't allow me to undo my downvote otherwise

Answer (score 10):

- [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) means private for current class and derived classes
- [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) means it can be used as-is but also be overridden in derived classes

Maybe it is better with some code instead of things you have probably already read, here is a little sample you can play with. Try removing the comments (//) and you can see that the compiler tells you that the properties cannot be accessed

```
[TestFixture]
public class NewTest
{
    [Test]
    public void WhatGetsPrinted()
    {
        A a= new B();
        a.Print();  //This uses B's Print method since it overrides A's
        // a.ProtectedProperty is not accesible here
    }
}

public class A
{
    protected string ProtectedProperty { get; set; }

    private string PrivateProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void  Print() // Since Print is marked virtual in the base class we can override it here
    {
        //base.PrivateProperty can not be accessed hhere since it is private
        base.ProtectedProperty = "ProtectedProperty can be accessed here since it is protected and B:A";
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I can be argued that the ***Most important*** distinction about `virtual`, is that this causes the compiler, when calling a method member polymorphically, ***which*** implementation to bind the compiled code  to.   When you call a member of a class from client code where the actual type of the object is, say derived class `foo`, but the variable it is being called on is actually typed (declared) as some base class, say `bar`, Members declared as `virtual` will bind to the implementation in the actual object type, (or to the most derived base class of the objects type that has an implementation).  Members *not* declared as virtual will bind to the implementation in the type that the *variable* is declared to be.

A.  **Virtual**.  then, if the member is declared as virtual, the implementation in the derived class will be executed even if the variable is declared as a base type.

```
  public class Animal
  { public virtual Move() { debug.Print("Animal.Move()"); }
  public class Bird: Animal
  { public virtual override Move() { debug.Print("Bird.Move()");  }
  Animal x = new Bird();  
  x.Move();   // Will print "Bird.Move"
```

B. **Not Virtual**.  When a member which is *not* declared as `virtual`, then the implementation will be chosen based on the declared type of the variable the method is executed on.  So if you have a Bird Object, in variable x declared as `Animal', and you call a method that is implemented in both classes, the compiler will bind to the implementation in the Animal class, not in Bird, even though the object is really a Bird.

```
  public class Animal
  { public Move() { debug.Print("Animal.Move()"); }
  public class Bird: Animal
  { public Move() { debug.Print("Bird.Move()");  }
  Animal x = new Bird();  
  x.Move();   // Will print "Animal.Move"
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to understand above two things properly, since both has different purpose.

**protected** is the type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.

The **virtual** keyword is for modify a method, property and allow it to be overridden in a derived class.