# New Modifier is not hiding Base class member

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop

I have an issue on `new` modifier keyword which is explained below in detail.

```
public abstract class RangeBase
{
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<int> ValueChanged;
    public int Minimum { get; set; }

    public void OnValueChanged(int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        ValueChanged(this, new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int>(1, 2));
    }
}
```

`RangeBase` is an `abstract class` defined a `RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler` of type `int`, a property `Minimum` of type `int` and a method `OnValueChanged` which accepts two `int` parameters.

```
public class MyRange : RangeBase
{
    public new event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double> ValueChanged;

    public new double Minimum { get; set; }

    public new void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        ValueChanged(this, new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double>(1, 2));
    }
}
```

`MyRange` class derived from `RangeBase` is also defined a set of fresh `members` and `methods` which has same name of Base class members but the type here is `double` and marked with `new` modifier keyword. Forget about `Generics` here.... Now let me explain the real issue.

Members and Properties marked with the `new` keyword hides the `BaseClass` Members and Properties of the same name. Here also this works well with me except `OnValueChanged` method. Intellisense still exposing both `Derived` and `Base` class `OnValueChanged` methods of type `int` and `double`. Here I Can hide Minimum property of type `int` in the `BaseClass` with the Minimum property of type `double` in `Dervied Class`. But it is not working for `OnValueChanged` method. Could anyone can explain why `new` keyword is not working in this situation. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: it's overloading, the new keyword is unnecessary.

Comment: The problem behind the issue: this is just not a good case for inheritance.

Comment: @RohitVats i have already defined a property called Minimum with a different type in the snippet

Comment: @YuliamChandra I agree this is overloading. But then what new keyword means

Comment: it simply hides base member when an instance is a derived type and the variable type that holds the instance is also a derived type, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809604/using-the-new-modifier-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @YuliamChandra could you please my question once more...

Comment: @VimalCK, I already explained, "it simply hides base member when an instance is a derived type and the variable type that holds the instance is also a derived type, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809604/using-the-new-modifier-in-c-sharp)"

Comment: @YuliamChandra I know why new keyword is using and what is overloading and overriding.. The question is if i can shadow a Property with a same name of different type then why it is not working for a method with same name with same no.of parameters but the parameter type is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hide a method which differs in signature, it will be treated as method overloading instead of [method hiding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> - A constant, field, property, event, or type introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members with the same name.
> - A method introduced in a class or struct hides all non-method base class members with the same name, and all base class methods with the
>     **same signature** (method name and parameter count, modifiers, and
>     types).
> - An indexer introduced in a class or struct hides all base class indexers with the same signature (parameter count and types).

Comment: Well, I've got the same problem and my signature is the same. Have a look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vYz2we

Intellisence, when typing `.Test(` shows both SomeService method and SomeAbstractService method too.