# virtual/override, new and not specified

Tags: c#

I get the difference between `virtual/override` and `new` modifiers. But what about times when I don't specify any modifiers.

For example I have `Animal` and `Cat` classes (`Cat` inherits `Animal`).

`Animal` class has method:

```cs
public void Say()
{
    // do something
}
```

And `Cat` class has method:

```cs
public void Say()
{
    // do something else
}
```

When I'm working with this methods they work as if I used `new` keyword.

Visual Studio shows me a warning (Use new keyword if hiding was intended).

Why does compiler won't break when I don't specify keyword. It just magically works with a little warning. Can I use some strict mode or may be edit settings in IDE.

Or may be it's a feature that I don't get :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# keyword usage virtual+override vs. new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new)

Comment: It is just a warning, reminding you that you are *probably* doing something wrong.  You probably are and meant Say() to be a virtual method.  The *new* keyword does only one thing, it suppresses the warning.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes I know I'm doing it wrong. I'm just curious why can I skip such important keyword.

Comment: You are allowed to do it wrong, you don't always have the luxury to modify a base class.  Sometimes it is useful, it works well in Winforms for example.  It relies heavily on Reflection so isn't so easily broken by a muddled inheritance chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does compiler won't break when I don't specify keyword.

To avoid the ["brittle base class"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/07/virtual-methods-and-brittle-base-classes.aspx) problem - where `Cat` originally has the `Say()` method, and then the author of `Animal` wants to add a `Say()` method too. With the current approach, that is *not* a breaking change - it will create a warning for the author of `Cat`, but that's all. The behaviour of all code will stay the same. The author of `Cat` can then decide what to do about their `Say` method - add the `new` modifier, or override `Animal.Say()` if that's virtual, or potentially rename the method to avoid confusion (if they control all clients as well).

Answer (score -4):

For Animal class `public virtual void Say()`. For Cat `public override void Say()`. Then always define object of type Animal:

```
Animal my_cat = new Cat();
my_cat.Say();
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all, as far as I can see.