# C# new in object declaration when inherit and override

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, new-operator, overriding

For example,

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual bool DoSomething() { return false; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override bool DoSomething() { return true; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo test = new Bar();
        Console.WriteLine(test.DoSomething());
    }
}
```

Why is the answer True? What does "new Bar()" mean? Doesn't "new Bar()" just mean allocate the memory?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be false? What would be the point in overriding the method? Perhaps you're interested in [method hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# keyword usage virtual+override vs. new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new)

Comment: I am thinking "Foo test" is to create an object test of Foo type,  although "new Bar()" is set. I don't know if there is a better explanation of memory allocation and objection creation. That would be much clearer for me to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Bar()` actually makes a new object of type Bar.

The difference between `virtual`/`override` and `new` (in the context of a method override) is whether you want the compiler to consider the type of the **reference** or the type of the **object** in determining which method to execute.

In this case, you have a reference of type "reference to Foo" named `test`, and this variable references an object of type Bar.  Because `DoSomething()` is virtual and overridden, this means it will call Bar's implementation and not Foo's.

Unless you use virtual/override, C# only considers the type of the reference.  That is, any variable of type "reference to Foo" would call Foo.DoSomething() and any "reference to Bar" would call Bar.DoSomething() no matter what type the objects being referenced actually were.

Answer (score 0):

`new Bar()` means create a new `Bar` object and call the default constructor (which does nothing in this case).

It returns `true` because `test.DoSomething()` returns `true`, as it has an override for `Foo` implementation (so the `Foo` implementation will not be called).

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo test = new Bar();
```

`test` is referring to a new object of `Bar`, hence the call `test.DoSomething()` calls the `DoSomething()` of the object `Bar`. This returns true.