# How to initialize an inherited class from string in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the necessity of dynamically create instance of a page (using selenium) at runtime. The idea is to retrieve the class name from a string and initialize it.

Let's say that I have a "GenericPage":

```
    public class GenericPage
    {
       public void Proceed(string testName)
       {
         //Basic implementation
       }
    }
```

The second class inherit from GenericPage implementing Proceed

```
public class WhatIsYourNamePage : GenericPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "fieldName")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "fieldSurname")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement UserSurname { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submit-first-inner-1")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement Submit { get; set; }

    new public void Proceed(string testName)
    {
        var userData = ExcelDataAccess.GetTestData(testName);
        UserName.EnterText(userData.fieldName, Costants.UserNameElementName);
        UserSurname.EnterText(userData.fieldSurname, Costants.SurnameElementName);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Submit.ClickOnIt(Costants.SubmitButtonElementName);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

So here it is what I have tried to dynamically create WhatIsYourNamePage:

```
var type = Type.GetType("WhatIsYourNamePage");
var myObject = (GenericPage)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
myObject.Proceed("LogInTest");
```

Issue is that in this way it calls GenericPage.Proceed, but I want WhatIsYourNamePage.Proceed.

Of course I can change:

```
var myObject = (WhatIsYourNamePage)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But I need to do this dynamically from a string. How?

Comment: Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you should declare `Proceed` method as virtual. Don't use `new` keyword to override the method in the inherited class (unless you really know what you are doing as it does not override method (OOP polymorphism) but hides it). So just `override` it with keyword override. If you do it in this way - the `myObject.Proceed("LogInTest");` will be called in the inherited class without further code changing.

Something like this:

```
public class GenericPage
{
   public virtual void Proceed(string testName)
   {
     //Basic implementation
   }
}

public class WhatIsYourNamePage : GenericPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "fieldName")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "fieldSurname")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement UserSurname { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submit-first-inner-1")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement Submit { get; set; }

    public override void Proceed(string testName)
    {
        var userData = ExcelDataAccess.GetTestData(testName);
        UserName.EnterText(userData.fieldName, Costants.UserNameElementName);
        UserSurname.EnterText(userData.fieldSurname, Costants.SurnameElementName);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Submit.ClickOnIt(Costants.SubmitButtonElementName);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although working with "new" methods hiding methods with the same name from a base class is always tricky, you can solve your problem by calling the method like this:

```
type.GetMethod("Proceed").Invoke(myObject, new[] { "LogInTest" });
```