# C# how to force override of non virtual unmodifiable method

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an issue while coding a DLC to a video game in C#.
There are two base classes that i can't touch because this is vanilla code :

- Booster
- Player

Player has a method "RedBooster" that takes an instance of "Booster" as parameter and calls one of its public methods :

```
using System;

public class Booster {
    
    private Player p;
    
    public Booster() {
        p = new Player();
        
        this.PlayerBoost();
    }
    
    public void walk() {
        
    }
    
    public void PlayerBoost() {
        p.RedBooster(this);
    }

}

public class Player {
    
    public Player() {

    }
    
    public void RedBooster(Booster b) {

        b.walk();
    }
    
}

//---------------------------//
// CAN'T TOUCH ALL OF THE ABOVE
//---------------------------//


public class PerpetualBooster : Booster {
    
    private Player p;
    
    public PerpetualBooster() : base() {
        p = new Player();
        
        this.PlayerBoost();
    }
    
    public void walk() {
        
    }
    
    public void PlayerBoost() {
        p.RedBooster(this);
    }
}
```

So "Player" calls the walk method and i'd like for it to call my OWN walk method of PerpetualBooster but Booster.walk isn't virtual so i can't override it.
What other choice do i have ?

Can I use reflection in any way ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can't override non-virtual/non-abstract methods. That's it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)

Comment: you could *hide* the base-implementation using the [`new` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) in your `PerceptualBooster`: `public new void walk()`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I already tried that but i doesn't work. It's always Booster.walk that is called

Comment: because the reference is of the base-type, not of your derived one. See my answer beyond.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot derive from a class and replace any of its members by something completely different - unless the designer of said class has made the member `virtual` or `abstract`.

You could try to *hide* the member instead using the [`new`-keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier):

```
public class PerpetualBooster : Booster {
    
    public new void walk() {
        
    }
}
```

However that will just create a second member having the exact same signature. So if you have a reference that points to your derived class but is of the base-type, you will still call the base-member:

```
Booster b = new PerecpectualBooster();
b.Walk(); // this will still call the base-method
((PerceptualBooster)b).Walk(); // while this will call your hiding method
```

Here you get some more details about the [differences between `virtual`, `override` and `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new).

Comment: That might have worked if I could change the way the method walk is called but i can't.
The call is in the game code that i can't change

Comment: Would have been good if you'd mentioned that in your question. Anyway if you cannot change the system, there's no way to extend it in any way.